# Extract then row.bind data.frames from nested lists

Tags: r, dataframe, nested-lists, rbind

I have a function that outputs a large matrix (Mat1) and a small dataframe (Smalldf1) I store them in a list called "Result".
This function is run inside a loop so I create many versions of my "Result" list until my loop ends....each time I add them to a list called "FINAL".

At the end of my loop I end up with a List called FINAL, that has many smaller "Result" lists inside...each containing a small dataframe and a large Matrix.

I want to rbind all of the small dataframes together to form one larger dataframe and call it DF1 - I'm not sure how I access these now that I'm accessing a list within a list..?

A similar question on here gave a solution like this:

```
DF1 <- do.call("rbind",lapply(FINAL, function(x) x["Smalldf1"]))
```

However this gives the output as a single column called "Smalldf1" with the description of Smalldf1...ie this is literally printed in the column list(X1="xxx", X2="xxx", X3="xxx")...I need this broken out to look like the original format, 3 columns housing the information...?

Any help would be great.

Comment: Please provide some example data using dput()

Comment: getting an error - Error in lapply() RHS appears to be a function name , but it cannot be found

Comment: Yes - this is what my data looks like..running your solution on this data i get this error: Error: cannot convert object to a data frame.

Comment: OK - it works on the 2nd element...it seems to work on your example just fine but for some reason i get an error on my code "RHS appears to be a function name, but it cannot be found"...I'm sorry I know you don't have my code, I can't share the output.

Comment: Please modify your question to include the result of this: `str(head(FINAL, 2))`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125894/discussion-between-paulbeales-and-agenis).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I make my comment into an answer. This could be your data:

```
df <- data.frame(X1=1:3, X2=4:6, X3=7:9)
FINAL=list(Result=list(Smalldf1=df, Mat1=as.matrix(df)),
             Result=list(Smalldf1=df+1, Mat1=as.matrix(df+1)))
```

You can combine `lapply` to extract the first (or Nth, just change the `1`) elements of the nested lists, and then do a rbind on this result, either with do.call or with dplyr:

```
#### # Doing it in base R:
do.call("rbind", lapply(FINAL, "[[", 1) )
#### # Or doing it with dplyr:
library(dplyr)
lapply(FINAL, "[[", 1) %>% bind_rows
####   X1 X2 X3
#### 1  1  4  7
#### 2  2  5  8
#### 3  3  6  9
#### 4  2  5  8
#### 5  3  6  9
#### 6  4  7 10
```

This should be your expected result

**WARNING:**
The solution using `dplyr` doesn't work for old versions of dplyr (i tested it on dplyr_0.5.0, but it returns an error on dplyr_0.2 for instance)