# extract specific rows from nested lists of class dist in r

Tags: r, list, nested, apply

I'm sure this question is a duplicate but I can't find the correct solution.  I have a large nested list, which is actually a list of class 'dist' outputs from lapply dist(). I now want to extract the last row from every list (since I only cared about the distance between the last rows of my original lists and all other rows in that same nested list.  I could convert this to a matrix, but that hasn't really helped me.

From a few related posts [Extract then row.bind data.frames from nested lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40082625/extract-then-row-bind-data-frames-from-nested-lists) and [R - Extracting information from list of lists of data.frames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41856001/r-extracting-information-from-list-of-lists-of-data-frames) and others I got closer.

I can extract the first element (corresponding to first columns) from every nested list using this, but I want rows:
    `sapply(df,'[[',1)`

This does something but not sure what exactly honestly:
`lapply(df, function(x) lapply(x, '[' , drop = FALSE))`

My original input into dist() was as follows. I have a nested list of 1000 lists that have x,y,z coordinates (there are many rows, here's an example):

`[[1]]
                          x             y             z
             -5.924184e-02 -0.0101882607  0.0017658100
             -8.884432e-02  0.0454085919 -0.1072237461
             1.495407e-02  0.0592509097 -0.0107400982

[[2]]
               5.211102e-02 -0.0141554617 -0.0176815372
              -2.861500e-02 -0.1155798724  0.0561973096
               2.230498e-03 -0.0264566373 -0.0501298532`

I then used this function to create 1000 distance matrices:

`lapply(orig.df[1:1000],dist) -> df`

Here's the top output from str(df)

```
str(df)
List of 1000
 $ :Class 'dist'  atomic [1:2628] 0.126 0.102 0.136 0.104 0.139 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "Size")= int 73
  .. ..- attr(*, "Labels")= chr [1:73] "2" "8" "10" "14" ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "Diag")= logi FALSE
  .. ..- attr(*, "Upper")= logi FALSE
  .. ..- attr(*, "method")= chr "euclidean"
  .. ..- attr(*, "call")= language FUN(x = X[[i]])
```

Basically what I now want to do is this:

```
df[1:1000][nrow(df),]
```

For all 1000 nested lists (distance matrices), take the last "row" and all "columns". This is a distance matrix of class dist. Seems simple enough but is giving me a hard time. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Are you asking for an example input into dist()? I'm trying to extract the last "row" of the distance matrix for all 1000 distance matrices which are all in a list (df).  I'll see if I can modify this.

Comment: *"I now want to extract the last row from every list"* Do you mean the last row from every `dist`ance matrix?

Comment: Yes, exactly! I have 1000 nested distance matrices. If I don't convert my df to a matrix they are class "list" and typeof "list" so I thought I was using the correct terminology. Thanks.

Comment: I did not downvote your question; but I imagine that the downvote is due to your post not including any reproducible minimal sample data which is always a critical component of [good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) asking how to do XYZ. I've posted an answer below (based on some minimal sample data), please take a look.

Comment: PS. Generally I agree with you in that downvotes can be difficult to interpret without any additional comments. However, the reason for downvotes are often very consistent: Lack of sample data, data/code as screenshots, no code attempt, multiple questions or no specific question. So I'd say that working through that list to see where your question falls short is usually a good starting point. If you've ticked all the boxes and still receive downvotes, that's when things get tricky. Either way, don't take DVs personal and do stick around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example using minimal sample data based on `mtcars`

```
lst <- lapply(1:3, function(x) dist(mtcars[, 1:3]))
```

We now extract the last row of every `dist`ance matrix from `lst`

```
lapply(lst, function(x) { mat <- as.matrix(x); mat[nrow(mat), ] })
#[[1]]
#          Mazda RX4       Mazda RX4 Wag          Datsun 710      Hornet 4 Drive
#         39.0532969          39.0532969          13.0751673         137.0145978
#  Hornet Sportabout             Valiant          Duster 360           Merc 240D
#        239.0487189         104.0715619         239.1388927          25.8745048
#           Merc 230            Merc 280           Merc 280C          Merc 450SE
#         19.8494332          46.6947535          46.7816203         154.9323723
#         Merc 450SL         Merc 450SLC  Cadillac Fleetwood Lincoln Continental
#        154.9059392         154.9757400         351.1951025         339.2020047
#  Chrysler Imperial            Fiat 128         Honda Civic      Toyota Corolla
#        319.0954246          43.7068644          46.1853873          51.4418118
#      Toyota Corona    Dodge Challenger         AMC Javelin          Camaro Z28
#          0.9055385         197.1289172         183.1486828         229.1781185
#   Pontiac Firebird           Fiat X1-9       Porsche 914-2        Lotus Europa
#        279.0373452          42.4123803           4.6529560          27.4191539
#     Ford Pantera L        Ferrari Dino       Maserati Bora          Volvo 142E
#        230.1029335          24.1431150         180.1581527           0.0000000
#
#[[2]]
#          Mazda RX4       Mazda RX4 Wag          Datsun 710      Hornet 4 Drive
#         39.0532969          39.0532969          13.0751673         137.0145978
#  Hornet Sportabout             Valiant          Duster 360           Merc 240D
#        239.0487189         104.0715619         239.1388927          25.8745048
#           Merc 230            Merc 280           Merc 280C          Merc 450SE
#         19.8494332          46.6947535          46.7816203         154.9323723
#         Merc 450SL         Merc 450SLC  Cadillac Fleetwood Lincoln Continental
#        154.9059392         154.9757400         351.1951025         339.2020047
#  Chrysler Imperial            Fiat 128         Honda Civic      Toyota Corolla
#        319.0954246          43.7068644          46.1853873          51.4418118
#      Toyota Corona    Dodge Challenger         AMC Javelin          Camaro Z28
#          0.9055385         197.1289172         183.1486828         229.1781185
#   Pontiac Firebird           Fiat X1-9       Porsche 914-2        Lotus Europa
#        279.0373452          42.4123803           4.6529560          27.4191539
#     Ford Pantera L        Ferrari Dino       Maserati Bora          Volvo 142E
#        230.1029335          24.1431150         180.1581527           0.0000000
#
#[[3]]
#          Mazda RX4       Mazda RX4 Wag          Datsun 710      Hornet 4 Drive
#         39.0532969          39.0532969          13.0751673         137.0145978
#  Hornet Sportabout             Valiant          Duster 360           Merc 240D
#        239.0487189         104.0715619         239.1388927          25.8745048
#           Merc 230            Merc 280           Merc 280C          Merc 450SE
#         19.8494332          46.6947535          46.7816203         154.9323723
#         Merc 450SL         Merc 450SLC  Cadillac Fleetwood Lincoln Continental
#        154.9059392         154.9757400         351.1951025         339.2020047
#  Chrysler Imperial            Fiat 128         Honda Civic      Toyota Corolla
#        319.0954246          43.7068644          46.1853873          51.4418118
#      Toyota Corona    Dodge Challenger         AMC Javelin          Camaro Z28
#          0.9055385         197.1289172         183.1486828         229.1781185
#   Pontiac Firebird           Fiat X1-9       Porsche 914-2        Lotus Europa
#        279.0373452          42.4123803           4.6529560          27.4191539
#     Ford Pantera L        Ferrari Dino       Maserati Bora          Volvo 142E
#        230.1029335          24.1431150         180.1581527           0.0000000
```

Comment: Thank you. That was easier than I was making it.